# How to access nested objects with replacer param json.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Here is a minified example of my problem:

```
var myObj = {hello: {bye: "bye"} };

JSON.stringify(myObj, ['hello']);

returns "{"hello": {}}"
```

**How can I access nested objects using the replacer array parameter?**

I researched posts demonstrating the "data" parameter in an ajax request, I am not making an ajax request, I am reading json, filtering properties, and writing the results to a new file.

Comment: The replacer can be a function too, you should be able do the logic you need.

Comment: @HelloWorld what exactly are you trying to do? If you're doing filtering of object values, it's probably better to use something like lodash/underscore for that.

Answer (score 3):

The following seems to work:

```
JSON.stringify(myObj, ['hello', 'bye']);
```

But couldn't find any documentation on the topic.

Comment: this does not effect nested objects in my trials

Comment: I haven't found an easy way to do that... initial thought was to just override JSON.stringify, add a 'global' replacer that applies the keys to keep to every nested call, but that's not how JSON.stringify works, if a property is not to be included in the result, any keys that don't match the replacer array are simply not traversed, e.g. the replacer never gets invoked...if someone has a nice and concise solution for this "problem", I'd love to know =)